# How to encode float/double/integer values in HBase?

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, hbase, hadoop2

I was encoding every column value as string to load data in HBase using the following:

```
put.add("columnFamily".getBytes(), new String(columnName).getBytes(), new String(value).getBytes())
```

That's why I was getting an exception

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: offset (0) + length (4) exceed the capacity of the array: 1
```

while reading the data, because one of the columns has float values (if I am not mistaken). There are few methods like `org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes.toBytes(float)` available but I don't know how to do it.

Could somebody tell me how can I encode float/double/integer value so that further reading data from HBase I will not get the same exception?
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do something like below:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes

val intNumber: Int = 100

put.addColumn(Bytes.toBytes("column_family_name"), Bytes.toBytes("column_name"), Bytes.toBytes(intNumber))
```

The above will save the number in HBase table in bytes format, in case if you want to save number in String format you can add `toString` to `intNumber` like below

```
put.addColumn(Bytes.toBytes("column_family_name"), Bytes.toBytes("column_name"), Bytes.toBytes(intNumber.toString))
```